# Is there a Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit book or reference

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, cntk

Is there a good reference or book for the Microsoft cognitive toolkit or CNTK.ai? Or any references for it such as a technical report. Are there related books on Azure Machine Learning Studio or Microsoft Cognitive APIs?

Comment: Either the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/pdfstore/en-us/Azure.azure-documents/live/cognitive-services.pdf, or this book (which I haven't read): http://a.co/7RVlYC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow their Github prfile[1] as the reference guide. On this page, you can find the specific instructions to setup the CNTK in your environment, tutorials, and examples that you could follow to get a basic understanding of toolkit.

[1] https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/

Answer (score 0):

For CNTK there's no book at this point. I would go through the materials under 
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/Tutorials and https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/Manual